# Detecting last activity on table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, `orders` and `orderNotes`:

```
orders:

orderID | customerID | orderName
--------+------------+-----------
   1    |     1      |  Test
   2    |     1      |  1234
   3    |     1      |  Test 2
   4    |     2      |  ABC Test

orderNotes:

noteID | orderID |      postedDate      | message
-------+---------+----------------------+----------
   1   |    1    | 2014-08-01 08:00:06  |  Testing
   2   |    1    | 2014-08-04 13:15:45  |  Hello
   3   |    2    | 2014-07-31 11:11:50  |  Hi, World
   4   |    2    | 2014-08-01 12:16:32  |  Test 123
```

<sub>...I think you get the idea</sub>

What I want to do is to detect if any order has *not* been updated in X hours.

I've come up with this:

```
SELECT orders.orderID, postedDate FROM orders
JOIN orderNotes ON orders.orderID = orderNotes.orderID
WHERE orders.customerID = 1
AND postedDate <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

but, this checks every row in `orderNotes`.  How can I get it to check only the *last* row?  I want to know if any orders (by `customerID = 1`) have not been updated in 2 hours.

Here's a demo of my current SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5fc2e/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work.

```
SELECT orders.orderID, MAX(postedDate) AS maxDate
FROM orders
JOIN orderNotes ON orders.orderID = orderNotes.orderID
WHERE orders.customerID = 1
GROUP BY orders.orderID
HAVING MAX(postedDate) <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5fc2e/16

Comment: Interesting, does it increase the query processing time? When I checked it, using EXPLAIN, it gave the same `Using temporary; Using filesort` AS the VIEW query.

Comment: I still get `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort`, but the query runs at a fraction of the time as the VIEW.  It's actually using the indexes, which the VIEW was not doing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Create a view with maximum dates

```
CREATE VIEW maxOrderNotes AS
SELECT
    orderID,
    MAX(`postedDate`) AS postedDate
FROM
    orderNotes
GROUP BY
    orderID;
```

#### Use the view in join

```
SELECT orders.orderID, postedDate FROM orders
JOIN maxOrderNotes ON orders.orderID = maxOrderNotes.orderID
WHERE orders.customerID = 1
AND postedDate <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;

+---------+---------------------+
| orderID | postedDate          |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2014-08-04 10:15:45 |
|       2 | 2014-08-01 12:16:32 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f571/1)

Comment: What is `CREATE VIEW`?  Is that like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE(...) ENGINE=MEMORY;`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, view is like a temporary table being populated on the fly

Comment: I tried running this and it worked, but when I ran it again it said `maxOrderNotes` already existed!

Comment: @RocketHazmat Don't run CREATE VIEW twice. It's like running CREATE TABLE twice. Just create a VIEW once and use it.

Comment: I've never used views before, so I don't know how to remove/update it.  Does it stay forever like a table?  Do I need to update it every time a row is added?  Why use a view when I could use a *real* table?  I'm not understanding this.

Comment: @RocketHazmat To remove it use DROP VIEW maxOrderNotes. Yes, it stays forever, like a table. "Do I need to update it every time a row is added?" - no, it is updated automatically by MySQL.

Comment: So, a view is part of the schema?  Does it use indexes?  Sorry, but this is completely new to me and I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat "So, a view is part of the schema?" - yes, you will see it, when running `SHOW TABLES`. "Does it use indexes?" - VIEW is like a stored query. If the query uses indexes, VIEW will also use it. To check it, run EXPLAIN with the VIEW query: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I'll need to try this.  It seems like it works, but I've never used it before, so I'll need to check the manual or whatever before actually using this.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sure, I think it's a better solution, then running a subquery. Because VIEW is compiled and MySQL doesn't spend time on parsing the query every time.

Comment: It looks like a cool solution!  I've never seen views before.  I want to test this out :)

Comment: It works, but it's ***super-slow***!  It's not using indexes.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this to use indexes!  It's painfully slow (~2 seconds to return 2 rows).

Comment: It looks like it's using something called `TEMPTABLE`.  That means it can't use indexes.  I want it use `MERGE`, but I can't because of the `MAX()`.  I can't use this solution, it's too slow.  Source: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16376

Comment: @RocketHazmat How big is your orderNotes table? There is only 1 way we can do it: create a new table and periodically insert maximum dates there, using a trigger.

Comment: Pretty big.  We have a lot of orders and each has lots of notes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The only way we can do it: is to create a table, insert all the maximum values there. And then add `ON INSERT`, `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` triggers to `orderNotes` table, updating the maximum date.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Hi, What if you add `HAVING MAX(postedDate) <= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` to the VIEW creation? Does it work faster?